# DateTime.Now Off By An Hour On Coworker's Computer

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a program that posts Datetime.Now(), but my coworkers computer's DateTime.Now() is off by an hour.

He changed it in his windows Date and Time Properties, but he is still posting a DateTime.Now() that is an hour off.

How can I fix this on his box without making modifications to my program (I have too many projects going on and need a quick fix for now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is he in the correct time zone? Better use DateTimeOffset.

Comment: I will check.   Would this make a difference?

Comment: Yes. It's quite likely something like daylight savings time, if not the time zone as such.

Comment: Does DateTime.Now change only when you restart the program? I think this is what was causing the problem.

Comment: No, it changes each time you call it (unless you call so frequently that not enough time has passed to make any difference to its value).

Comment: @Steven, then I'm completely stumped.  My coworker's timezone and daylight savings settings were all fine, and his time is fine too.  This is really bugging me out! :S

Comment: @Soo: So the time shown in the bottom right corner of his screen is correct, and the time zone and DST are correct, but `DateTime.Now` differs from yours?

Comment: @Steven: Yes, I saw it with my own eyes on his computer, I'm stumped.

Comment: @Soo: Obvious follow-up question, given Hans' response: Does his `DateTime.UtcNow` differ?

Answer (score 3):

Ask him to enable daylight savings time observance and to verify the timezone.  And in general use DateTime.UtcNow.  Ask more questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: Yes, I will implement UtcNow with the next release of my program :)

Comment: Using UTC is a very good idea, particularly in a distributed system. It does mean that, in some cases, you will need to convert to the user's time zone for presentation purposes, but that's worth the trouble.

Comment: Definitely, the conversion is pretty simple too.  The posting time is having a negative effect on how the program works, so I agree, it definitely will be worth the trouble.