# DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff") results in a string one hour later on some machines

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I'm modding a C# Unity game (2020.3.26f, Mono 4.6.57.0) with BepInEx 5.4.19. In my mod, I create a file with a filename containing the current time formatted:

```cs
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff") + ".dat";
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + filename, "blah,blah");
```

On my machine, this results in a filename that aligns with the last modification date of the file created when looking at it from Explorer:

`20220524_132000_123.dat        <last modified: 2022.05.24 13:20:00>`

(My timezone is CEST)

However, one of the users of this mod reports that they get a filename that is one hour later than what the filesystem shows, for example:

`20220524_143000_456.dat        <last modified: 2022.05.24 13:30:00>`

The time for when the user did the save was at 13:30 so the filename is off by one hour for some reason. (Their timezone is GMT+3)

Why is there such a one hour difference on their machine but not on mine?

#### Edit:

After a bit back-and-forth with the user, it turns out the problem is with the user's Windows' timezone registry keys that are not up-to-date for some reason.

As for the duplicate pointing to `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, it is no good because the users want to see the same time in the filename itself and in the filesystem. In other words, if I make a save at 15:50 local time, the filename should have 1550 in it, not 1350 or 1650.

Comment: I didn't understood well your question but you can try with the `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone?view=net-6.0) you got the documentation about that property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime.Now Off By An Hour On Coworker's Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718748/datetime-now-off-by-an-hour-on-coworkers-computer).   See the accepted answer and that left by Mr Passant.

Comment: Don't use `DateTime.Now` - as it's subject to daylight savings and incorrect computer timezone settings - you should always use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` for network-safe(r) machine-invariant time values.

Comment: What does their computer/Windows clock say the time is? How are they viewing the File Last Modified date, exactly?

Comment: They have the correct clock in the taskbar, they have DST off because they no longer do that in their country. They look at the last modified date in Windows Explorer. UtcNow is not good because now the filenames are two hours behind (on my end). The users will look at the filenames and find the hour wrong.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect Mono 4.6.57.0 (2016?) Unity uses. Does .NET bundle the timezone database with each of its versions? If so, the outdated database still applies DST apparently.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is with the user's Windows' timezone registry keys that are not up-to-date.